# React Native Video - undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Image.propTypes.resizeMode'

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I'm using `react-native-video` in `react-native v0.69` withing nx monorepo and when trying to add Video component like below, I get an error `TypeError: undefined is not an object  (evaluating '_reactNative.Image.propTypes.resizeMode'`.

```
import Video from 'react-native-video'

  <Video
     resizeMode="none"
     source={{ uri: _.url }}
     style={{ width: 64, height: 64 }}
  />
```

When i remove `resizeMode` prop I get same error.
What is causing this?

Answer (score 8):

I've managed to solve it. For react-native `0.69`,`^6.0.0-alpha.1` version of react-native-video fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

We have to install `6.0.0-alpha.1`, but `pod install` can give some errors. But those error's can be resolved using below commands:

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

and then go to the iOs folder and run:

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

It will work.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the `package.json` file and remove:

```
"react-native-video": "^6.0.0-alpha.1"
```

Then type: `npm i` in terminal